# How to prepare shallot greens?

Tags: culinary-uses, shallots

I have a bunch of shallots with the greens (stems) on them, and I was wondering if anyone has experience with them.  How are they used? Throw them in with the shallot bulbs? Use them like green onions or chives? What dishes are good with them (or require them)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally use them exactly like chives, though their flavour may be more intense.

Comment: Agreed, they're a bit stronger in flavour indeed.

Comment: Used them last night in a risotto--they had a nuttier flavor than chives, which I enjoyed very much.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, you could also pickle them. We have pickled ramps at the restaurant right now (homemmade of course). Pickling would mellow out the harshness of the flavour, and be a guaranteed "what is that and why is it so good?" when you feed them to guests.

(Note that we use, and I would advise, a fairly straight up brine, and not the more fermented sort of pickle as that gets into issues of bacteria management and such. Alton Brown did a very informative Good Eats episode on making pickles should you decide to go the fermented route.)